# MySQL is not accepting ISO string as DATE

Tags: mysql

MySQL database won't accept an ISO string, and is throwing this exception:

> incorrect date value: '2019-02-20T10:00:00.000Z' for column 'dueDate' at row 1`.

The date is being formatted like this: `this.state.dueDate.toISOString()`, as an ISO string. Also, on the local MySQL server, there is no error thrown. It only fails my  private Ubuntu server.

This is the table schema:

```
| tickets | CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `component` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf32 COLLATE utf32_romanian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `startDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dueDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reporter` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignee` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `estimation` float DEFAULT '0',
  `priority` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `lane` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `project` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `releaseID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `releaseID` (`releaseID`),
  KEY `assignee` (`assignee`),
  KEY `reporter` (`reporter`),
  KEY `category` (`category`),
  KEY `component` (`component`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `ticket_assignee_null` FOREIGN KEY (`assignee`) REFERENCES `users` (`email`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `ticket_comp_delete` FOREIGN KEY (`component`) REFERENCES `components` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `ticket_release_null` FOREIGN KEY (`releaseID`) REFERENCES `releases` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `ticket_reporter_null` FOREIGN KEY (`reporter`) REFERENCES `users` (`email`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `tikcet_category_null` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Trying to change the default charset results in this error:
`Cannot change column 'assignee': used in a foreign key constraint 'ticket_assignee_null'`
.

Comment: Please update your question with the table schema and MySQL version number. You can get the table schema by running the query `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MySQL manual covers the formats it recognizes in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html

```
mysql> select DATE( '2019-02-20T10:00:00.000Z');
+-----------------------------------+
| DATE( '2019-02-20T10:00:00.000Z') |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2019-02-20                        |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2019-02-20T10:00:00.000Z'
```

You can either change the format before you use the date literal in MySQL, or you can use [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) on the ISO date literal.

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE( '2019-02-20T10:00:00.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ');
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE( '2019-02-20T10:00:00.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-02-20 10:00:00.000000                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Using `STR_TO_DATE` worked, in combination with `DATE()` like so: `DATE(STR_TO_DATE(?, "%Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ"))`

Answer (score 0):

the issue is about your character set and collation settings. compare your local db's character set and collation settings with the one within Ubuntu. You will see the issue.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'char%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  '%colla%';
```

please note that collation and character set settings may differ on the schema, table and also even column level.

Comment: I was thinking about collation, but the ubuntu database is being imported from the one I use locally. There is no collation on date, but I will check.